# Python: How to match user input with case insensitive answer?

Tags: python

Ok, so Ive just started learning python and I've got an assignment that's asking me to create a quiz. I've already figured out how to make it case sensitive, but I'm having trouble with the user inputed answer. When I try to run the program to verify that it's the correct answer it just tells me that the inputed answer is not defined.

Here's a sample of my current code (Don't judge the stupid question, I had a major writers block :P ):

```
q1= "1. What is the name of the organelle found in a plant cell that produces chlorophyll?" 
plantcell=input(q1)  
ans1= "chloroplast" 
if plantcell.lower()==ans1.lower(): 
    print("Correct!") 
else:
    print("Incorrect!")
```

I'm using python 3 and Wing IDE 101. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the exact error.

Comment: Please explain your problem better. What exactly do you do, and what exactly is the error (if you get an exception, paste the exception traceback in your question, don't just describe it). When I run this code in Python 3.4, it does exactly what it sounds like you want it to.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the full traceback

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet your real problem is that you're *not* using Python 3.

For example, maybe you're on a Mac, and you didn't realize that you already have Python 2.7 installed. So you installed Python 3.4, then installed an IDE, and assumed it must be using your 3.4 because that's all that's there, but it's actually defaulted to 2.7.

One way to verify this is to `import sys` and `print sys.version`.

In Python 2.7, `input` is the equivalent of Python 3's `eval(input(…))`. So, if the user types `chloroplast`, Python is going to try to evaluate `chloroplast` as a Python expression, which will raise `NameError: 'chloroplast' is not defined`.

The solution is to find out where you configure the default Python version in your IDE, and configure it for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I also assume that the problem is that you are accidentally using Python 2. One way to make you code run in both versions of Python would be to either use something like `plantcell = str(input(q1))` or even better (and more secure) use `raw_input` (which is equivalent to Python 3's `input`. Below is an example:

```
import sys

q1 = "1. What is the name of the organelle found in a plant cell that produces chlorophyll?" 

if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    plantcell = input(q1)  
else:
    plantcell = raw_input(q1) 

ans1 = "chloroplast" 
if plantcell.lower() == ans1.lower(): 
    print("Correct!") 
else:
    print("Incorrect!")
```